# Spring Data Rest resource processing failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I'm attempting to use Spring Data Rest resource processors to add a link to a resource; however, during `MockMvc` integration testing, it blows up with a class cast exception, complaining that an `EmptyCollectionEmbeddedWrapper` cannot be converted to `ResourceSupport` (the bounds of the `ResourceProcessor`'s parameterized type):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.hateoas.core.EmbeddedWrappers$EmptyCollectionEmbeddedWrapper cannot be cast to org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceProcessorInvoker$DefaultProcessorWrapper.invokeProcessor(ResourceProcessorInvoker.java:225) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceProcessorInvoker.invokeProcessorsFor(ResourceProcessorInvoker.java:142) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceProcessorInvoker.invokeProcessorsFor(ResourceProcessorInvoker.java:119) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.handleReturnValue(ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.java:114) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:130) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
```

It's expected that the returned value should be empty at this point (as `EmptyCollectionEmbeddedWrapper` suggests), but of course the class cast is not intended. As the stack trace suggests, this exception occurs during resource post processing; if I remove a simple resource processor I have for this type, the class cast exception disappears and the request succeeds. This is surprising to me, because the resource processor is essentially lifted from the documentation.

In more detail, the resource parameter type is `Notification`; the `MockMvc` request that fails looks like:

```
perform(get(entityLinks.linkToSearchResource(Notification.class, NotificationRepository.ACTIVE_SEARCH)
            .expand(Collections.singletonMap("projectId", 1)).getHref()))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.notifications").isEmpty());
```

And the `ResourceProcessor` looks like:

```
@Bean
public ResourceProcessor<Resource<Notification>> notificationResourceProcessor(RepositoryEntityLinks entityLinks) {
    return notificationResource -> {
        notificationResource.add(entityLinks.linkToCollectionResource(NotificationAction.class));
        return notificationResource;
    };
}
```

I assume I've got something misconfigured, because this seems like a very basic usage of Spring Data Rest. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

After debugging in ResourceProcessorInvoker found that the resolved type for the ResourceProcessor was not `ResourceProcessor<Resource<T>>` (in your case `ResourceProcessor<Resource<Notification>>`) as expected, but `ResourceProcessor<T extends ResourceSupport>>`. The reason is the creation of the the processor using lambda.
Creating the anonymous class in the old fashion way solved the issue in my case:

```
@Bean
public ResourceProcessor<Resource<Notification>> notificationResourceProcessor(RepositoryEntityLinks entityLinks) {
    return new ResourceProcessor<Resource<Notification>>() {
        @Override
        public Resource<Notification> process(Resource<Notification> notificationResource) {
           notificationResource.add(entityLinks.linkToCollectionResource(NotificationAction.class));
           return notificationResource;
        }
    };
}
```